# What is this emacs configuration doing?

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.saves")))
```

I know that it's setting the directory where backup files are saved, but I don't understand specifically what the `` `(("." . "~/.saves")) `` part is doing. Specifically:

1. What is the ` mark doing? (also, does that thing have a special googleable name?)
2. Why does this require double parenthesis? It's like this in the [default settings](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory), not just in my configuration file.
3. It seems like the solitary `.` inside may be some kind of substitution operator and I notice that I have another similar line with a comma instead. What is the operation that these things are doing?

My google-fu has failed in the face of figuring out what punctuation marks do in lisp and I'm too lazy to work through the emacs lisp tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [`backup-directory-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html) does explain most of this. The value is an [association list](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) where each key is a [regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html). The simple regex `"."` matches every non-empty string, so it applies to every directory name.

An association list is read from beginning to end, and it's easy in Lisp to prepend a new association:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      (cons '("\\`/tmp/" . "/tmp/saves")
      backup-directory-alist))
```

... or more succinctly

```
(push '("\\`/tmp/" . "/tmp/saves") backup-directory-alist)
```

... to end up with a list with two settings: a specific one for paths matching the regex `` "\\`/tmp/" `` in front if the generic one for all other paths.

You wrote a [backquote](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) but the proper way to quote the expression is with a regular [quote](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html).

The dot between the alist key and the value is a [cons](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/cons.html), a primitive for creating lists. As a practical matter, a cons is simpler than a list, so you can get the value with a straight [`cdr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/car-_0026-cdr.html), rather than the conceptually more complex [`cadr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html) (the `car` of the `cdr`).

I don't think you can have a comma in that position (though comma has a use in backquotes).

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful, especially with the edited expansion.

Comment: Another term is quasiquote.  I once saw an explanation that made a lot of sense to me.  The default in lisp is for things to be unquoted, and the `'` quotes them.  The quasiquote `\`` flips this around, so that things are quoted by default and unquoted with `,`.